# Error Message When Executing Using Direct Query to execute a stored procedure with parameters in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, openrowset, directquery

I am trying to run a SQL Server stored procedure in Power BI that has parameters and I am getting this error:

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=SQL
> DataSourcePath=xxx-xxxxxx\xxxxx;xxxx
> Message=Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
> ErrorCode=-2146232060
> Number=2
> Class=16
> State=1

```
Source  = Sql.Database("xxx-xxxxxx\xxxxx", "xxxx", [Query="SELECT * FROM #(lf)OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','trusted_connection=yes', 'exec xxxx..sp_storedprocedure @StartDate=" & StartDate & ", @EndDate=" & EndDate & "')", CreateNavigationProperties=false])`
```

Above is what the advanced editor has. I know it is not the named pipes in the SQL Server config manager because it is enabled and other queries work fine in PowerBI. I have also restarted the SQL Server services a number of times but no luck as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Demo_kpi] @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

AS

--Set @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0);
--Set @EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1);

--SELECT
SELECT [Snapshot_ID]
      ,[Cost to Complete]
      ,[Cost to Complete (SS)]
      ,[CtC PM Notes]
      ,[CtC Variance]
      ,[PCOs]
      ,[PM Manual CtC Override]
      ,[Previous Month (CtC)]
      ,[Project]
      ,[Project Number]
      ,[Projected Contract]
      ,[Projected Over/Under]
      ,[Remaining Exposure]
      ,[Revised Contract]
      ,[Total Cost Incurred]
      ,[UnitCode]
      ,[Approved COs]
      ,[Cost Code]
      ,[CPCOs]
      ,[Current Commitment]
      ,[Invoices]
      ,[Original Budget]
      ,[Original Commitment]
      ,[ImportDate]
      ,[CtC Modifications Notes (Previous Month)]
    ,@StartDate AS StartDate
    ,@EndDate AS EndDate
 FROM [Buckingham].[dbo].[tbl_UnitTracker_NonReno_Snapshot]
    WHERE ImportDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 101)
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 101);
```

Comment: your connection defines named pipes, which only work on localhost, but on your computer is no sql server installed or named pipes disabled

Comment: Thanks @nbk. I tried running the same thing on the server and gave the same error message and the named pipe is enabled. If there is another way to call a stored procedure with parameters using direct query in Power BI without using the OPENROWSET option, I'd gladly use that but I don't think there is...

Comment: this show how you can do it https://databear.com/sql-stored-procedures-in-power-bi/

Comment: Thanks but the step 4 didn't work. Gave a cyclic reference during evaluation error

Comment: then add the error to your question with the link, so that we can understand what you are doing

Comment: Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation. https://databear.com/sql-stored-procedures-in-power-bi/ @nbk

Comment: always edit your question with new information and whenb you are at can you add also your stored procedure

Comment: Thanks @nbk but the stored procedure runs well. It is a basic select statement that takes start and end dates as input parameters to give a set of fields. The issue is not the stored procedure but how Power BI executes it.

Comment: i still belive that the stored prcedure is a problem, and if it so basic so post it

Comment: Minor correction... the Shared Memory protocol only works on the local computer, but the TCP/IP protocol and Named Pipes protocol can both work from remote clients. Named Pipes protocol is undesirable, though, because it requires additional ports to be open for RPC to work (similar ports to File and Printer Sharing).

Comment: When you restart your SQL Server service(s) are you also restarting the SQL Browser service? SQL Browser service only enumerates the SQL Server ports and pipes at startup and doesn't check them again for changes. This can be problematic when SQL Server service(s) are configured to use dynamic ports, or get reconfigured, because SQL Browser will not detect those changes and will continue to report the old information.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes. I restart both services when I do and have even restarted the server once. It's strange because I have been connecting via remote clients for over 6 months with no issues.

Comment: I've added the stored procedure @nbk